# "Dead Zone" in multiple-monitor configuration

Tags: snow-leopard, display, mouse, mac-pro

This question concerns a Mac Pro running 10.6 with 2 monitors set side-by-side and configured as one big monitor. Recently I have found that sometimes a "dead spot" appears to my USB Apple mouse in the lower right quadrant of my left monitor. When my cursor was in this area, nothing was clickable (making a window active, scroll bars, buttons, etc.) on that part of the window. Other parts of that window that were out of the dead zone were clickable. I noticed that some of my Safari windows straddled the junction of the two monitors, so when I dragged those windows to be totally in the left monitor, the problem **seems** to have gone away. Any ideas as to what might be going on? I have had this hardware configuration for several years but this problem is very recent. Thanks.

Comment: Are they running at the same resolution? Also, try and adjust the layout in Display Preferences by dragging the two screen representations apart and snapping them back together.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your System Preferences -> Displays -> Orientation Tab?

Comment: What do you mean by "one big monitor" are you using a third party device or card to power your monitors? Does your menu bar extend across both monitors or live on one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Check the layout of your displays in the "Displays" preference pane:

[image: Screenshot]

Normally it's not possible to position your displays such that there is an actual *gap* between them (at least on Lion), but perhaps moving them around will fix the problem.